# window.AppInventor in Angular 4

Tags: angular, app-inventor

I have a local application in Angular 4 which uses localStorage on the desktop browser to persist data. I'm using a WebViewer in AI for the application.

I know localStorage cannot be used in AI2 and need to use the WebViewString or any other data storage. I also know how to check if the application is running in AI or desktop browser using window.AppInventor in Javascript.

My question is -
How do I check if the application is running in AI using Angular 4 ?
So that i can use localStorage for the desktop and WebViewString for AI

I tried using window.AppInventor in my Angular code, but get an error

```
Property 'AppInventor' does not exist on type 'window'
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer for this :)

I needed to get the reference for the Javascript window object in Typescript.
Once I get the reference, its the same as using the window object in Javascript.

https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-get-window-ref/

Take a look at the above link for more details on getting the native window reference.
Once we get the reference, it can be used like

```
if (this.winRef.nativeWindow.AppInventor) {
    this.persistData = JSON.parse(this.winRef.nativeWindow.AppInventor.getWebViewString());
} else {
    this.persistData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("floodPersist"));
}
```